# Is there a way to store lines output by last command in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to filter and record information from the last command using a Bash script. I was wondering if there is any way to store the lines from the last command as a variable (like an array) so that they can be filtered and edited.

My first thought was trying `` varname=(`last`) `` to try and just record the information directly into a new variable, but this only records for the characters up to a space of a single line, and records it as a single string. Is there some way to record all of the lines from last as an array or other variable?

For reference, each line of last is formatted as tabulated data. An example line looks like:

`abc0123  pts/01     127.0.0.1   Sat Oct  3 20:54   still logged in`

or

`abc0123  pts/01     127.0.0.1   Sat Oct  3 20:53 - 20:54  (00:01)`

Comment: try referrencing your variable like `echo "${varname[@]}"` and make that `v=( $(last) )` ;-) . Good luck

Comment: Gave it a shot, but I still get the same issue when it comes to ```v```, where it's just the first piece of data from the first line.
For reference: each line in last is data,tab,data,tab,data,tab,data (without the commas)

Comment: I was just being lazy with `v=...` ;-). more interested in dragging you into the 90's and using "modern" `$(command_substitution)` ;-)... I just tried `v=( $(echo abc0123  pts/01     127.0.0.1   Sat Oct  3 20:54   still logged in) )` and then `echo ${v[@]}` and got back `abc0123 pts/01 127.0.0.1 Sat Oct 3 20:54 still logged in` . It would work or multi line input too, but there is probably something I'm forgetting. better in general to use something like `last | while read uID port ip day Mon Date Time status; do echo $uID, $ip, $status ; done > rptfile`. Going to bed. Good luck ;-)

Comment: `array=( $(somecommand) )` is an antipattern for the reasons given in [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29)

Comment: Your original code really does store an array. You're probably only *printing* its first element. That's what `echo $array` does, for example; it prints only the very first element.

Comment: If you want to read line-oriented data info an array, use `mapfile` or `readarray`, as given in the above link.

Comment: The echo I was using was ```${testVar[0]}``` which was only giving the uID part of the whole line. This technically can work, since the other parts are recorded in further array spots, but my hope was to have the entire line per variable. The other downside to using that method was that parts like "still logged in" are split up, when I would have to read them later.

Comment: my new intention with shellter's second comment, it i can use the while loop in the last command to record to a text file, and then read that text file into an array and delete the text file

Comment: May I ask what will you do with these data? like print them again in different format? calculate times, count logins? call any commands based on them?

Comment: The general idea is to filter the data in order to list the current logged in users, and then every ten seconds list any changes to who is logged in. Essentially the program would just run until SIGINT is used to stop it

Comment: You can use commands like `w` and `who` combined with `watch` or without, and have what you want, without the need to parse the text output of commands, which is considered not a good practice, see link for bash pitfalls above and see that simple case with different field at the end of line, text or time, in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone, I think I managed to achieve what I'm looking for. I'm using the loop from shellter to record ```w``` to a file, and using readarray to transfer that to an array, before deleting the file. Now I've got all the logged in users recorded, giving me all the data I need. Thanks again for everyone who responded, I learned a lot more than I thought I would.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a separate array entry for every line, set IFS temporarily to the newline symbol for the assignment.

```
IFS='
' A=(`printf 'a b\nc d'`)
echo "Line 0: ${A[0]}"
echo "Line 1: ${A[1]}"
```

will output

```
Line 0: a b
Line 1: c d
```

If instead you want everything as a single variable, you do not need any bashisms:

```
variable="`printf 'a b\nc d'`"
echo "$variable"
```

will output

```
a b
c d
```

Note that the latter removes possible spaces at the end of the last line. If you want to avoid that, you need a trick:

```
variable="`cmd; echo A`"
variable=${variable%A}
```